# How do I call function from jade client side java scripts

Tags: node.js, pug

I have two drop down lists in my form. Once user selected value from first list I want to filter second list as per selection and display. For that I am using onchange="showSubCat(); of first select option to get selected value. showSubCat() function is defined in client side js file. How do I get value returned by showSubCat() function in jade template so that I can filter array which is populating second list.

```
var subcode = showSubCat();
```

gives error.

Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you try `mixin showSubCat()?`

Answer (score 4):

New to Jade myself but as far as I can tell you have two options:

1) create the function in jade itself:

```
-function sayHi(name){
   - return "hello "+name
-}
p= sayHi('bill')
```

Which I think muddies up your code a bit.

2) A better option would be to pass in the function from the model

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){  
    res.render('home', { 
        title: 'Home'
        , fs: { sayHi:function(name){
            return "hello "+name
        }}
    });
});
```

Then in your jade file you just:

```
p= fs.sayHi('bill')
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, option (1) is invalid in Jade. It doesn't compile in the latest version. All Javascript directives must have their scope fully encompassed on a single line.